# More descriptive failure message using custom matcher with mockedResource.expects(where(???)) in ScalaMock

Tags: scala, logging, scalatest, scalamock

I'm working with ScalaMock and ScalaTest to put together some unit tests. I want to use the ScalaMock's expectation syntax to confirm that the service I'm working on passes along acceptable Json to a mocked resource. In this case acceptable means some internal fields can be different, so I've written a custom function to determine whether the fields I care about match. The problem with this is that it produces relatively unhelpful logging when the expectations are not fulfilled. The expectations set as in:

```
(mockedResource.doAThing(_: Json)(_: SomeImplicitThing))
  .expects(
    where(
      jsonSimilarAndImplicitEqual(
        expectedJson,
        anInstanceOfImplicitThing
      )(_, _)
    )
  )
```

Produce the following logging on failure:

```
- should forward acceptable Json to the mockedResource
  Unsatisfied expectation:

  Expected:
  [info]   inAnyOrder {
  [info]     <mock-1> MockedResource.doAThing<function1> once (never called - UNSATISFIED)
  [info]   }
```

I'd like to be able to provide some custom logging function to describe why `jsonSimilarAndImplicitEqual` evaluated to false in a sensible place. I was hoping an `inAnyOrderWithLogging` block would prove sufficient, but it turns out I can't even use this construct, since it is not supported for AsyncMockFactory.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [specs2-mock](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.2.0/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html) (a wrapper for Mockito) instead of ScalaMock, and use an [argument captor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/index.html?org/mockito/Captor.html). Using the `org.specs2.Mockito` trait, you can write `val captor = capture[String]` and then `there was one(value).method(captor.capture)`. Once you've captured the argument, you can use scalatest `Matchers` to do assert the relevant properties.